# how to repeater show data when button click in asp?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a button click event. I want to show data in repeater when I click button.
how to use `bindRepeaterData` in a click event?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindRepeaterData();
    }
}


protected void clickme(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     protected void BindRepeaterData( )
    {
      con.Open();

      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select question from question where tag='asp'", con);
      int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      da.Fill(ds);
     RepDetails.DataSource = ds;
     RepDetails.DataBind();
     con.Close();
    }

}
```

repeater code from .aspx file where repeter code is RepDetails

```
 <div >
    <asp:Repeater  runat="server" ID="RepDetails"  >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table class="op">
            <thead>
            <tr> 
               <td>
                   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="question" Text=' <%#("question") %>' ></asp:Label>
               </td> 
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call BindRepeaterData(); inside the button click event.

```
  protected void BindRepeaterData( )
{
  con.Open();

  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select question from question where tag='asp'", con);
  int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  da.Fill(ds);
  RepDetails.DataSource = ds;
  RepDetails.DataBind();
  con.Close();
}

protected void clickme(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 BindRepeaterData();
}
```

Comment: Can you post  your button control??

Comment: when i not use button its work fine but i want data show when i click.

Comment: according to you when i Call BindRepeaterData(); inside the button click event.its show error compilation error

Comment: "CS1513: } expected"           show error  under the click event but all code are closed.

Comment: Can you update the information? Post the control in asp controls too. I need more information.  If your method binds correctly in Page_Load event, It should work in Click event as well.

Comment: I have clarified my answer on what I mean on "Call BindRepeaterData();". I only meant call the method. Just Like what you did in Page_Load.

Comment: ohhh sorry sorry i trying i think now i can solved probem thanks.

Comment: Glad to be at help.